# How to make parcelable class with nested classes

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I'm new in Android dev. And I was faced with the fact that I need to redo my class into Parcelable class. And the main problem with it is that i have 3 nested classes into my class.

It is my code:

```
class Test      (var id: Int,
                 var numberQuestion: String,
                 var question: String,
                 var questionImageSrc: String,
                 var examination: Boolean,
                 var typeQuestion: String,
                 var singleChoiceAnswers: ArrayList<singleChoiceAnswer>,
                 var multipleChoiceAnswers: ArrayList<multipleChoiceAnswers>,
                 var inputAnswer: ArrayList<inputAnswer>): Parcelable{

    constructor(source: Parcel): this(
        source.readInt(),
        source.readString(),
        source.readString(),
        source.readString(),
        source.readByte(),
        source.readString(),

        // ????

        )

    companion object{
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR = object: Parcelable.Creator<Test>{
            override fun newArray(size: Int) = arrayOfNulls<Test>(size)
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel?): Test {
                return Test(source!!)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.writeInt(id)
        dest?.writeString(numberQuestion)
        dest?.writeString(question)
        dest?.writeString(questionImageSrc)
        dest?.writeValue(examination)
        dest?.writeString(typeQuestion)
        dest?.
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}

data class multipleChoiceAnswers(var letter: String,
                                 var text: String,
                                 var correctAnswer: Boolean,
                                 var checked: Boolean)

data class singleChoiceAnswer(var letter: String,
                              var text: String,
                              var correctAnswer: Boolean,
                              var checked: Boolean)

data class inputAnswer(var correctAnswer: String,
                        var userAnswer: String)
```

I need to make nested classes Parcelable too ? And i take data from JSON. If you need here is a [link](http://sasmobile.ru/resources/ege/dataJSON/russianLanguage/tests/russianLanguageTest.json)

Thank you in advance) 
P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to do all that. Just use `@Parcelize` [from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html).
Annotate all theses classes with `@Parcelize` and make them extend `Parcelable`. You can remove all your `Parcelable` related code in the `Test` class.

Also I'll recommend modifications for a few things wrong that I see in your code :

- Turn all your `var` properties to `val`. It will enforce immutability, one of Kotlin's basic features. The same goes for your `ArrayList`s, use `List` instead to disallow modifications of the list. If you really can't have a read-only `List` then use `MutableList`. It's more easy to understand that it's a read/write list than when you use `ArrayList`.
- Make your `Test` class a `data class`. I don't see why not benefit from it in your case.
- All classes name must begin with an uppercase. `multipleChoiceAnswers` -> `MultipleChoiceAnswers`. It's a convention we follow in many languages, not just Kotlin.